# rake db:create rake aborted error

Tags: ruby, fedena

Am installing fedena on windows 10. My ruby version is 1.9.3 and gem version is 1.8.29 and rails version 2.3.5. When I run the command it gives out the following output. Am new to Ruby any suggestions as to how I can solve this?

```
C:\fedena>rake db:create
rake aborted!
Could not find test-unit (= 1.2.3) amongst [actionmailer-2.3.5, actionpack-2.3.5, activerecord-2.3.5, activeresource-2.3
.5, activesupport-2.3.5, bigdecimal-1.1.0, i18n-0.4.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.5, minitest-2.5.1, mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw
32, prawn-0.6.3, prawn-core-0.6.3, prawn-format-0.2.3, prawn-layout-0.3.2, prawn-security-0.1.1, rack-1.0.1, rails-2.3.5
, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-4.2.2, rdoc-3.9.5, rubytest-0.8.1, test-1.0.0]

(See full trace by running task with --trace)


C:\fedena>rake db:create --trace
rake aborted!
Could not find test-unit (= 1.2.3) amongst [actionmailer-2.3.5, actionpack-2.3.5, activerecord-2.3.5, activeresource-2.3
.5, activesupport-2.3.5, bigdecimal-1.1.0, i18n-0.4.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.5, minitest-2.5.1, mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw
32, prawn-0.6.3, prawn-core-0.6.3, prawn-format-0.2.3, prawn-layout-0.3.2, prawn-security-0.1.1, rack-1.0.1, rails-2.3.5
, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-4.2.2, rdoc-3.9.5]
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
C:/fedena/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `block in load_with_ne
w_constant_marking'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_with_new_constan
t_marking'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
C:/fedena/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Your Rails version is almost 7 years old. It has known security issues and bugs. Same for your Ruby version that also is outdated. Did you consider updating your app?

Comment: Do you have the `test-unit` gem in the version `1.2.3` installed?

Comment: Run `gem list` in terminal

Comment: Run `gem environment ` in terminal

Comment: Show output from commands above

Comment: There is no test unit @spickermann

Comment: @farhatmihalko when I do a gem list and gem environment it looks like the output on this link http://pastie.org/10901805

Comment: @T.Mumba: You need to install the `test-unit` gem in the version `1.2.3` then, because your error message tells you that it `Could not find test-unit (= 1.2.3)`

Comment: @spickermann did gem install of test unit and it successfully installed test-unit 3.2.0 which in my view is higher than 1.2.3 and issuing rake db:create still produced the same error

Comment: @T.Mumba. You cannot just install any version, because the error message tells you that exactly version `(= 1.2.3)` is required (note the `=`, it would work if it were `>`).

Comment: @spickermann tried to install gem 1.2.3 and it brings another error could not find a valid gem '1.2.3' <>= in any respository. Any alternatives?

Comment: How did you try to install that gem in the specific version? Because that gem is still available on [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/test-unit/versions/1.2.3)

Comment: @spickermann did gem install test-unit -v 1.2.3 and it successfully added the gem but running rake db:create again brings the error rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask.

Comment: `spec/rake/spectask` was part of an old RSpec gem version (probably version around version 1.3.0). It seems like you are still missing gems. Don't you have a documentation about the dependencies? Why do you have to work with such an old application?

Comment: @spickermann I was sticking to the recommended versions according to installation guide on www.fedena.org but seems there are a whole lot of issues. maybe I should try installing on Linux. Do you recommend another alternative on Windows?

Comment: uninstall current rake version and install rake 0.8.7

Comment: @Navin thanks will try that

Answer (score 1):

The application you are trying install is written in ruby 1.8.7 and you are trying to run on ruby 1.9
Use this [guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fedena/Installation) for installing fedena